# Canvas: adding canvas.width does not work inside "setInterval"

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, setinterval

Here is my code:

```
var text = "3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952035301852968995773622599413891249721775283479131515574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012858361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534646208046684259069491293313677028989152104752162056966024058038150193511253382430035587640247496473263914199272604269922796782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165344987202755960236480665499119881834797753566369807426542527862551818417574672890977772793800081647060016145249192173217214772350141441973568548161361157352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219222184272550254256887671790494601653466804988627232791786085784383827967976681454100953883786360950680064225125205117392984896084128488626945604241965285022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573962413890865832645995813390478027590099465764078951269468398352595709825822620522489407726719478268482601476990902640136394437455305068203496252451749399651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753928468138268683868942774155991855925245953959431049972524680845987273644695848653836736222626099124608051243884390451244136549762780797715691435997700129616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467678895252138522549954666727823986456596116354886230577456498035593634568174324112515076069479451096596094025228879710893145669136867228748940560101503308617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998948722658804857564014270477555132379641451523746234364542858444795265867821051141354735739523113427166102135969536231442952484937187110145765403590279934403742007310578539062198387447808478489683321445713868751943506430218453191048481005370614680674919278191197939952061419663428754440643745123718192179998391015919561814675142691239748940907186494231961567945208095146550225231603881930142093762137855956638937787083039069792077346722182562599661501421503068038447734549202605414665925201497442";
var pi = [];
pi = text.split('');
$('document').ready(function () {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 15;
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    canvas.style.border = '1px solid';
    canvas.border = 'solid 1px';
    canvas.style.top = '0px';
    canvas.style.left = '0px';
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    draw();
});

function draw() {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if(i < 50) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(15 * i, 100 - pi[i] * 10);
            ctx.lineTo(15 * (i + 1), 100 - pi[i + 1] * 10);
            ctx.stroke();
            i++;
            canvas.width += 15;
            //console.log(i);
        };
    }, 100)
}
```

It totally works if I comment out

```
canvas.width += 15;
```

If I keep it there, `canvas.width` does increase, but the lines do not show up.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

The problem solved by putting the width before the line.

## But here is my further question: how to draw the lines successively? Right now the older one disappears after the new one.

Comment: The problem solved by putting the width before the line. Here is my further question: how to draw the lines successively? Right now the older one disappears after the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that changing the canvas width resets the canvas state, including what is currently drawn on it. If you increase the width prior to creating the line, both of the events occur as expected.

In order to keep the previous paths after the state of the canvas is reset, you can create a temporary canvas to hold the content and later move back once the width is adjusted.

```
function draw() {
    var i=0;
    setInterval(function() {
        if (i<50) {
            // Create a temporary canvas
            var temp_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var temp_ctx = temp_canvas.getContext("2d");

            // Update the temporary canvas width (will reset temporary canvas state) and draw original canvas back in
            temp_canvas.width = canvas.width + 15; 
            temp_canvas.height = canvas.height;
            temp_ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

            // Draw temporary canvas back into original canvas
            canvas.width = temp_canvas.width; 
            canvas.height = temp_canvas.height;
            ctx.drawImage(temp_canvas, 0, 0);

            // Draw in new path
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(15*i, 100-pi[i]*10);
            ctx.lineTo(15*(i+1), 100-pi[i+1]*10);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();

            i++;

            //console.log(i);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nmPdU/3/)**

Comment: Thank you. It works! BTW, how to draw the lines successively? Right now the older one disappears after the new one.

Comment: @uhaojane Please see my updated answer. Also, please consider upvoting and/or accepting answers that provide valid solutions to questions.